# How to use Manipulate for Finite Differences

Tags: matrix, manipulate, finite-difference-method

I want to improve my code using the command Manipulate and being able to see the calculus of averages as the indexes *l* and *u* are moved. I did a simple example of a 4x4 matrix with the boundary conditions all equal to 1. The initial conditions are all equal to zero. What I have to do is to calculate the new entrance (2,1) of the matrix  so I average the initial point with respect to its 4 neighbors and then I replace that mean with the element (2,1) of the initial matrix. I did this 4 times and it works:

```
G = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
l = 2; 
u = 2;
prom1 = Mean[{G[[l - 1, u]], G[[l + 1, u]], G[[l, u - 1]], 
    G[[l, u + 1]]}];
G1 = ReplacePart[G, {2, 2} -> prom1]
l = 2;
u = 3;
prom2 = Mean[{G1[[l - 1, u]], G1[[l + 1, u]], G1[[l, u - 1]], 
    G1[[l, u + 1]]}];
G2 = ReplacePart[G1, {2, 3} -> prom2 ]
l = 3;
u = 2;
prom3 = Mean[{G2[[l - 1, u]], G2[[l + 1, u]], G2[[l, u - 1]], 
    G2[[l, u + 1]]}];
G3 = ReplacePart[G2, {3, 2} -> prom3  ]
l = 3;
u = 3;
prom4 = Mean[{G3[[l - 1, u]], G3[[l + 1, u]], G3[[l, u - 1]], 
    G3[[l, u + 1]]}];
G4 = ReplacePart[G3, {3, 3} -> prom4 ]
```

I know my code could be much more elegant so I tried to use *While* with this condition to stop the iterations:

`N[Norm[G - G4]] < 0.5`

The problem is when I tried to put all together with the idea of making a loop. This is what I tried:

```
Manipulate[{MatrixForm[
    G = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}], 
   MatrixForm[
    G1 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, prom, prom, 1}, {1, prom, prom , 1}, {1, 
       1, 1, 1}}]}
  While[N[Norm[G - G1] < 0.5],
   prom = 
    Mean[{G[[f - 1, n]], G[[f + 1, n]], G[[f, n - 1]], G[[f, n + 1]]}];
   G1 = ReplacePart[G, {f, n} -> prom];
   G = Replace[ G, {G -> G1}]] , {f, 2, 3, 1}, {n, 2, 3, 1}]
```

Comment: Your usage of `Manipulate` is confusing. What are you trying to _see_ with `Manipulate`? Or you just want to simplify the first code sample?

Comment: I want to simplify the first code sample. That's the reason because I use two indexes f and n, to move from (2,2) to (2,4) but then I want to repeat this process until the difference between G and G4 (the norm) be less than 0.5. I mean, G4=G and repeat the process

Comment: Then `Manipulate` isn't for the task. It's for visualization. Please check the document of `Table`.